# retrieve an item in the Parse Array

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-activity, parse-platform

I have managed to store an array of items in parse using the below code:

```
currentUser.add("Users", currentUser);
```

I would like to retrieve an item from the array and cast it to a TextView that would be displayed to the user. I would like to retrieve the first item on the list. How would I be able to retrieve the second first item on the list, third first item on the list?

I have attempted the following:

```
   ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");
                   query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser()
                           .getObjectId());


                   query.setLimit(1);
                   TextView mUserNameRetrieved = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvname1);


                   mUserNameRetrieved.setText(objects.get(i).get("UserMatch").toString());
```

but unfortunately this has lead to the following null point exception error:

```
10-04 05:20:48.000: E/AndroidRuntime(3774): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-04 05:20:48.000: E/AndroidRuntime(3774): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-04 05:20:48.000: E/AndroidRuntime(3774):     at com.dooba.beta.matchOptionActivity$1.done(matchOptionActivity.java:134)
10-04 05:20:48.000: E/AndroidRuntime(3774):     at com.parse.FindCallback.internalDone(FindCallback.java:45)
10-04 05:20:48.000: E/AndroidRuntime(3774):     at com.parse.FindCallback.internalDone(FindCallback.java:31)
10-04 05:20:48.000: E/AndroidRuntime(3774):     at com.parse.Parse$6$1.run(Parse.java:937)
10-04 05:20:48.000: E/AndroidRuntime(3774):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
10-04 05:20:48.000: E/AndroidRuntime(3774):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-04 05:20:48.000: E/AndroidRuntime(3774):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-04 05:20:48.000: E/AndroidRuntime(3774):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-04 05:20:48.000: E/AndroidRuntime(3774):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-04 05:20:48.000: E/AndroidRuntime(3774):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-04 05:20:48.000: E/AndroidRuntime(3774):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-04 05:20:48.000: E/AndroidRuntime(3774):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-04 05:20:48.000: E/AndroidRuntime(3774):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand from your explanation, you want to query the Parse User class. However, Parse treats User objects separate from Parse objects. In other words, you cannot query the User class via using ParseQuery.getQuery(). Instead you have to use ParseUser.getQuery(). The API explanation is in below link;

https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#users-querying

Hope this helps,
Regards.